# Oracle server session terminated by fatal error

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an Oracle server running on Windows Server.

When an `INSERT` statement runs I receive an Oracle `Ora-00603` error.

The insert statement just tries to insert a BLOB into a table.  I searched the error specification on Google and found that perhaps there are network connection issues. The suggested action is to log in again to Oracle Server. I followed this tip, however I still receive the same error.

The error I receive is the following:

> ora-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error

I am using an Oracle 10 client. My application is a C# application. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "anything happens"? Do you perhaps mean nothing happens? How big is the blob that you are trying to insert?

Comment: Do you use user sys or a normal user? Or a table in system schema?

Comment: I receive the same Oracle server error. The length is about 1500. I run as normal user.
I also tried to check the alert log, but there is no mention about error.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to perform the insert?

Comment: I suppose tablespace has enough space. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. The code is just a stored procedure with 2 input parameters.

Comment: Your question is tagged [oracle9i] but you say you're using an Oracle 10 client.  I'm a little concerned about using a client with a higher version number than the database.  If the server is really Oracle 9i you might try installing the 9i client software and trying again.  Good luck.

Comment: You say you've checked the alert log, but have you also checked whether there are any trace files in the background destination directory?

Comment: The server is really Oracle 9i. I'm constrained using Oracle 9i because the application was developed according to this standard. However I'm running Windows 7 which has several issues with 9i client. No, I've not checked out trace files. I'm unaware about which kind of information they provide.